# Not Found The requested URL /about was not found on this server. laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wamp, wampserver

I got an error saying

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

I have this routes

```
Route::get('/', 'megamitch@index');
Route::get('home', 'megamitch@index');
Route::get('about', 'megamitch@about');
Route::get('loan-products', 'megamitch@loanproducts');
Route::get('careers', 'megamitch@careers');
Route::get('contact', 'megamitch@contact');
```

if I do "php artisan route:list" I can see that those routes really exist. Im running on wamp server where that issue exist (same issue on the live web server), however if i run my app through "php artisan serve" all pages works. Any ideas, help?

PS: only this route "Route::get('/', 'megamitch@index');" works.

Comment: Does `/index.php/about` work? If so, then your apache config isn't rewriting URLs.

Comment: yes it work, how im going to configure apache config so that it will rewrite url or what are the fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your rewriting isn't working. If you add `index.php` to the URL right before the `/about` does it work?

For example, `yourdomain.com/about` would become `yourdomain.com/index.php/about`

If your rewriting isn't working, but you have the `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory, then you probably need to allow overrides in your apache configuration. Here is an example virtual host configuration for WAMP and Laravel.

I've marked the lines you need to change. Change the first and third to point to the `public` directory in your website's directory. Then change the second line to the domain name you're using with your website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/yourdomain/public"      # Change this line
    ServerName yourdomain.com                         # Change this line
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/yourdomain/public">       # Change this line
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All    # This line enables .htaccess files
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to restart Apache for these settings to take effect.

Comment: im missing an httaccess ont he /pulic/ that solve issue.

Comment: This solution (enable mod_rewrite for virtual host) worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/423549/493153